# Entity Framework 6.0 One to Many relationship is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I try to use Entity Framework with code first and fluent api to implement a one to many relationship

On the one side, I have the **ClassDefinitionEntity** class :

```c#
 public class ClassDefinitionEntity{   

    public string LocalClassIsin { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity> PublishingDefinitions { get;  set; }

    public ClassDefinitionEntity()
    {
        PublishingDefinitions = new List<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity>();
    }
}
```

And on the many side the **PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity** class:

```c#
public class PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public ClassDefinitionEntity ClassDefinition { get; set;}
    public PcfFormatEnum Format { get; set; }
    public PcfPublishingChannelEnum Channel { get; set; }
}
```

My column names do not follow entity conventions so the code in **OnModelCreating** is like this:

```c#
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
...
        modelBuilder.Entity<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity()
           .ToTable("IFM_PCF_PUBLISHING_DEFINITION");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity>()
           .HasKey(e => new { e.ClassId, e.Channel, e.Format });
        modelBuilder.Entity<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity>()
           .Property(e => e.Channel)
           .HasColumnName("PUBLICATION_CHANNEL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Format)
            .HasColumnName("PUBLICATION_FORMAT");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.ClassId)
            .HasColumnName("CLASS_ID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PcfPublishingDefinitionEntity>()
            .HasRequired(pd => pd.ClassDefinition)
            .WithMany(cd => cd.PublishingDefinitions)
            .HasForeignKey(pd => pd.ClassId);
...
}
```

But It's not working. The **PublishingDefinitions** collection is always empty.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Based on the config, I would say it looks OK.
Your collection might be empty for other reasons: do you have lazy-loading disabled by any chance?

Comment: Did you try adding `Include(e => e.PublishingDefinitions)` to your `ClassDefinitionEntity` retrieving queries? Or make the collection property `virtual` if you want lazy loading behavior.

Comment: @AkosNagy: thx for the update, I've checked the OnModelCreating for the LazyLoadingEnabled property. It's not set. I want eager loading.

Comment: @IvanStoev Where would you add the Include ? My query is just an access to the DbSet.

Comment: For instance, when you do something like `db.Set<ClassDefinitionEntity>().Include(e => e.PublishingDefinitions).Where(...).ToList() / FirstOrDefault()` etc. Basically in any query that returns `ClassDefinitionEntity`.

Comment: @IvanStoev thx for your update Ivan. The DbSet<ClassDefinitionEntity> Include method has only one signature with a string in input. I'm using EF 6.1.3

Comment: You are welcome. The method I had in mind is located in `QueryableExtensions` class, so you need `using System.Data.Entity;` in order to get access to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard convention for one-to-many or many-to-many in EF I think is lazy loading meaning you have to tell the db to include the collection when you fetch the data from the db. If you are using linq use .include.

EG:

```
yourdbcontext.ClassDefinitionEntity.Include(x => x.PublishingDefinitions).ToList();
```

[Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: my DbSet<ClassDefinitionEntity>.Include method does only take strings, not lambda functions ...

Comment: Not sure why your include method doesnt take a lambda function, I have tried this with EF 6 and EF core and in both cases they accept a lambda expression. Maybe try using Idbset instead? Or putting all your dbset in a class that inherits from Dbcontext. Also check your using statements and your version of EF. Otherwise the string path should be "PublishingDefinitions" and this should work in your include method.

Comment: @IvanStoev made this clear in his comment: the Include(Func<T,U> path) method is located in the **QueryableExtensions** class  in the **System.Data.Entity** namespace

Comment: I think that when using Include to force EF to load the entities would be Eager Loading, according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 1):

If Lazy Loading is enabled, make sure to include the word `virtual` to the relationship. This would help EF to load lazily that entity or entities. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data for more information about Lazy Loading and how entities are loaded when such functionality is enabled.

[image]